# Possibility to set cursor shape manually in Neovim

Tags: neovim, cursor

New versions of neovim handle cursor shapes perfectly. But for a special use case I need to change cursor shape manually for a while. Is it possible in Neovim > .2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with this commit: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/dd4a5fcbb65ade08b5d2c7951b2924d2d04dc99e

I had to use nightly build to be able to use it. To change cursor shape in terminal all you have to do is set `guicursor`.